# Highlight Top Row in Excel for Only Cells with Values | MS Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Essentially I have the following code I use in MS Access after Exporting an Excel.
This works well for Applying the Filter Functionality and Making the Cell Values Bold, but how can I also highlight the cells of those same values?

```
   'Specifying Tables

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Table1",".xlsx", True


DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Table2",".xlsx", True

Call ModifyExportedExcelFileFormats(".xlsx", "Table1")

Call ModifyExportedExcelFileFormats(".xlsx", "Table2")
```

__

```
Public Sub ModifyExportedExcelFileFormats(sFile As String, sSheet As String)

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlSheet = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFile).Sheets(1)



With xlApp
        .Application.Sheets(sSheet).Select
        .Application.Rows("1:1").Select
        .Application.Selection.Font.Bold = True
        
        .Application.range("A1").Select
        .Application.Selection.AutoFilter
        
        
        .Application.Cells.Select
        .Application.Selection.Columns.AutoFit
        .Application.range("A1").Select
        
        .Application.Activeworkbook.Save
        .Application.Activeworkbook.Close
        .Quit
   End With
```

End Sub

How can this properly used to only highlight the cells in the top row that have values in them?

```
        .Application.Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow
```

Comment: `Range([whatever]).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Interior.Color = vbYellow`?

Comment: Could probably set Conditional Formatting rule.

Comment: I've updated my post with some more context, can a conditional rule be applied to the spreadsheet through MS Access VBA? All formatting I apply to it now is done in silently after I export

Comment: You mean just highlight the top row?

Answer (score 0):

This does work:
`Range([whatever]).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Interior.Color = vbYellow`

But if users will be editing data, might want to set Conditional Formatting rule. It is not necessary to actually select cells to modify properties. Using `ActiveAnything` syntax can cause issues with automation code. Better to use explicit reference.

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFile)
With xlWb.Worksheets(sSheet).Range("A1:G1")
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Columns.AutoFit
    .FormatConditions.add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=LEN(TRIM(A1))>0"
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
End With
xlWb.Worksheets(sSheet).Range("A1").AutoFilter
xlWb.Save
xlWb.Close
xlApp.Quit
```

Comment: The script stops at  `.FormatConditions.add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=LEN(TRIM(A1))>0"` saying invalid argument

Comment: Code works for me. Why don't you do what I did - use Excel macro recorder to generate code then adapt it for Access procedure.